# AFNetworking does not pluralize my data model objects correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ios, afnetworking

I'm building an iOS + Rails app using **AFNetworking** and **AFIncrementalStore** for the client-side API requests, using the AFIncrementalStore default example as starting point: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFIncrementalStore/tree/master/Examples/Basic%20Example

My main data object is called "Activity", and thus pluralized to "Activities" - my index page is `http://localhost:3000/activities.json`

However, I can see in the Xcode log that AFNetworking somehow pluralizes to "activitys":

```
Error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.networking.error Code=-1011
"Expected status code in (200-299), got 404" UserInfo=0x6da64a0
{NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:3000/activitys,
NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 404}
```

Can I change this behavior? Also I'd like to stick a `.json` suffix to the URL.

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround in the new Twitter example provided by AFIncrementalStore:

```
// Inside "MyAPIClient.m"

- (NSURLRequest *)requestForFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)fetchRequest withContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {
    NSMutableURLRequest *mutableURLRequest = nil;
    if ([fetchRequest.entityName isEqualToString:@"Activity"]) {
        mutableURLRequest = [self requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"activities.json" parameters:nil];
    }
    return mutableURLRequest;
}
```